# How to select unique values from 10 latest rows in SQLite on android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, activeandroid

I have a table with column which contains measurements. I want to get 10 lat rows and get from it unique values.

I try:

```
select distinct * form Table group by Measurement_X order by Measurement_X asc;
```

in active android I use:

```
new Select().distinct().from(Table.class).groupBy("Measurement_X").orderBy("Measurement_X ASC")
```

when I add to above statements "limit 10" it seems to limit distinct values not count of rows which is used determine distinct.

So, how to get distinct values from lasts rows?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Limit` keyword, like

```
select distinct * form Table group by Measurement_X order by Measurement_X asc LIMIT 0,10;
```

then you can get `top 10` data's